# sprintf not giving expected values

Tags: c, printf, hex, type-conversion, bitconverter

I have an array (readingreg[4]) that gets filled with hex digits. My goal is to convert the datatype into a string. I have read some suggestions and it seems that sprintf is the way to go.

This is what I tried:

```
sprintf(server0, "0x%02X", readingreg[0]);
printf("This is element 0: %s\n", server0);

sprintf(server1, "0x%02X", readingreg[1]);
printf("This is element 1: %s\n", server1);

sprintf(server2, "0x%02X", readingreg[2]);
printf("This is element 2: %s\n", server2);

sprintf(server3, "0x%02X", readingreg[3]);
printf("This is element 3: %s\n", server3);


printf("This is element 0: %s\n", server0);
printf("This is element 1: %s\n", server1);
printf("This is element 2: %s\n", server2);
printf("This is element 3: %s\n", server3);
```

Here is my output:

```
This is element 0: 0x4A
This is element 1: 0xAA
This is element 2: 0xAA
This is element 3: 0xA0
This is element 0: 0
This is element 1: A0
This is element 2: xA0
This is element 3: 0xA0
```

At this point, I am pretty confused on what sprintf has done for me. My expected output is that server0 - server4 all retain their string values. Any idea to why this is occurring?

Here is a simplified version of the program:

```
readingreg[0] = 4A;
readingreg[1] = AA;
readingreg[2] = AA;
readingreg[3] = A0;
char server0[1];
char server1[1];
char server2[1];
char server3[1];
```

The full program is over 1000 lines of code so what I provided should be sufficient enough to compile and run.

Comment: How are server0-3 initialized? Looks like pointers to stack allocated single characters instead of buffers...?

Comment: The `serverx` variable declarations are key to the question.  Don't leave them out of the code you posted.  As a matter of fact, what would be so hard in posting a full program so that all we need to do is copy/paste in our code editor and run it?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that can be copy/pasted and compiled as-is.

Comment: I will edit my question to include the declarations of serverx along with a SSCCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
char server0[1];
sprintf(server0, "0x%02X", readingreg[0]);
```

you are trying to put 5 characters (don't forget the trailing '\0') into a 1 character buffer. This results in undefined behaviour which happens to show itself in the observed output.

What you should do (at least) is make the character buffer large enough to store whatever you are putting in it:

```
char server0[8];
sprintf(server0, "0x%02X", readingreg[0]);
```

A better solution would be to make the array larger *and* use `snprintf()` or a similar function to ensure you don't overflow the character buffer:

```
char server0[8];
snprintf (server0, sizeof(server0)/sizeof(server0[0]), "0x%02X", readingreg[0]);
```

Comment: If just using `sprintf`, not only should the buffer be "just large enough", but larger than expected.  Too many programmers cut corners and try to predict, down to the exact byte, how big to make their buffer.  That almost always leads to memory overwrites.

Comment: Alright I just tried snprintf() and used the syntax you demonstrated above. When I do a printf of server0[0] as %s, the console prints garbage. Im expecting server0[0] = '4' and server0[1] = 'A'

Comment: Don't do `printf("%s", server0[0]);` as that is UB. You want to do `printf("%s", server0);`.

Comment: I ended up going with your first suggestion - creating a buffer large enough and using sprintf to do the conversion. It worked out. Thanks man.